# Access ProcessId and StageId in Dynamics CRM Plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm writing a plugin on Campaign which used a Business Process Flow. The fields ProcessId and StageId which are created by the Business Process Flow in Campaign Entity. I need to retrieve these values for a record in my plugin.

They don't appear in the Plugin Registration Tool's Step Image. They don't even appear in CRM workflows were I can populate them in some other field.

Is there a good alternative on how I can achieve this?

Comment: My Dynamics CRM version is CRM 2015 Online.

Comment: Just an update to post here - D365 v9 has now deprecated StageId, ProcessId fields in entities in Oct 2018 release. Hope this helps for people looking for the fields info on BPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve this by passing the correct input parameters to a `workflow activity` in this business process flow.

1) if you have these string inputs:

```
[RequiredArgument]
[Input("Process Name")]
public InArgument Process { get; set; }

[RequiredArgument]
[Input("Process Stage Name")]
public InArgument ProcessStage { get; set; }
```

2) Execute code `Get Process`:

```
using (var _context= new OrganizationServiceContext(service))
{   
   // Get the processid using the name provided
   var process = (from p in _context.CreateQuery()
                  where
                  p.Name == Process.Get(executionContext)
                  &&
                  p.StateCode == WorkflowState.Activated
                  select new Workflow
                  {WorkflowId = p.WorkflowId}
                 ).FirstOrDefault();
   if (process==null)
       throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(string.Format("Process '{0}' not found",Process.Get(executionContext)));
```

Get the `stage id` using the name provided

```
var stage = (from s in _context.CreateQuery()
             where
             s.StageName == ProcessStage.Get(executionContext)
             &&
             s.ProcessId.Id == process.WorkflowId
             select new ProcessStage
             {ProcessStageId = s.ProcessStageId}
            ).FirstOrDefault();
if (stage == null)
    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(string.Format("Stage '{0}' not found", Process.Get(executionContext)));
```

You can now `Change` `Update` the stage with your values retrieved ...

```
Entity uStage = new Entity(context.PrimaryEntityName);
uStage.Id = context.PrimaryEntityId;      //
uStage["stageid"] = stage.ProcessStageId; //retrieved stage 
uStage["processid"] = process.WorkflowId; //process id
```

Comment: Thanks Shane! I wanted it in the Image of the plugin registration step since I'm using it already. I think I would need to make a call to CRM instead.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just grab a service from your `IServiceProvider`, and retrieve the fields?

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    IPluginExecutionContext context = CommonPluginLibrary.GetContextFromIServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
    IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
    IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

    Entity campaign = service.Retrieve(context.PrimaryEntityId, context.PrimaryEntityName, new ColumnSet("processid", "stageid"));

    // ...
    // Do your stuff with campaign["processid"], campaign["stageid"]
    // ...
}
```

---

Another approach would be creating two *shadow* fields for `stageid` and `processid` (e.g. `new_stageid`, `new_processid`), and populating these fields using a **synchronous workflow** that triggers on process/stage update.

Then, you could register your plug-in on these *shadow* fields as they would be your entity's custom attributes.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to retrieve it in the Image of the plugin registration step. I think it's not available there.

Comment: hello, unfortunately no, it isn't available. i've updated my answer with another approach, if you're still interested in not making service calls within your plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

To access process and stage ids you can use processid and stageid fields of record. I'm pretty sure that you can get it from Images or through direct read of a record. Additionally you can recheck following article:
https://deepakexploring.wordpress.com/tag/updating-process-id-in-crm-2013/

Comment: Hi. Thanks, I was expecting it to be available in the Image of the Plugin Registration tool step. I would need to make a call Retrieve call to CRM.